# R: reading in a text file with the paste function

Tags: r, paste

I think this should have a simple answer but I haven't found it yet. Basically, I want to make a function that calls and reads in a text file. Here's what I have (I'm writing this in ui.R file of a Shiny function, but I don't think that's part of the problem):

```
popovers <- function(pop_name){
  fileName <- paste0("\'",pop_name,".txt\'")
  js <- readChar(fileName, file.info(fileName)$size))
  js
}
```

Right now, I can't even concatenate `fileName` since I get the error "cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'" from the `paste0` function. Any ideas on how to fix this? Is this the correct method of reading in various .txt files?

Comment: Usually that error means that the only object called `pop_name` that R can find is a function, and it can't coerce that to character. But debugging that further is impossible with the information you've provided. There are lots of ways to read in a text file, depending on what you want. There is `read.table`, `readLines`, `scan`, etc.

Comment: What is the output of `str(pop_name)`?

Comment: make sure you're passing `popovers("string")` instead of `popovers(string)`.

Comment: @MichaelChirico That did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from combining different suggestions from the comments. Here's the correct code:

```
popovers <- function(pop_name){
  fileName <- paste0(pop_name,".txt")
  js <- readChar(fileName, file.info(fileName)$size))
  js
}
```

I deleted the extra quotes around the ____.txt name and made sure to pass `popovers()` a string in quotes, such as `popovers("string")`. As long as the ___.txt file is in the working directory, it should properly read it in!